# Twilio SMS verfication using Parse Cloud not delivering

Tags: parse-platform, twilio

I'm using Parse cloud to send SMS for verification. this is my cloud js code im using

```
function sendCodeSms(countryCode, phoneNumber, code) {
    var promise = new Parse.Promise();
    twilio.sendSms({
        to: countryCode + phoneNumber,
        from: twilioPhoneNumber,
        body: 'Your login code for TestApp is ' + code
    }, function(err, responseData) {
        if (err) {
            console.log(err);
            promise.reject(err.message);
        } else {
            promise.resolve();
        }
    });
    return promise;
}
```

On Twilio Logs status says "Sent" but it is never delivered. Not sure what I'm doing wrong? It was working fine 2 days ago.

Here is the screenshot https://i.stack.imgur.com/ukbnk.png

Answer (score 1):

Twilio developer evangelist here.

That code all looks correct and you're getting the message to Twilio, so that's all fine.

The status "sent" means that the message has been accepted by a carrier, however it is only when the message is "delivered" that the user should have received it. [See the meanings of statuses here](https://www.twilio.com/help/faq/sms/what-do-the-sms-statuses-mean).

The other thing I noticed was that the number you sent to in your screenshot was an Indian number. [There are some restrictions on sending to Indian numbers which you can read about here](https://www.twilio.com/help/faq/sms/are-there-limitations-on-sending-sms-messages-to-indian-mobile-devices).

If you are doing phone verification/two factor authentication, you might be interested in [Authy](https://www.authy.com/developers) which allows you to perform those tasks in an easier way than just using Twilio. It can also do login code via an authentication application rather than SMS, which may be helpful in this situation too.

Let me know if this helps!

Comment: its not only indian numbers, i tried chinese and US but it always says "sent" . infact when i submitted my app to itunes 2 days ago it was working but today apple rejected the app saying the sms is not working. So i tried now and looks like it just says SENT thats it.

Comment: Could you share your Account SID with me over email so I can take a closer look at this? You can get me at philnash@twilio.com